# Eloquent Table Relationships

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hello i just realized how very confused i am by these relations, I have a question i need to ask. Assuming i have two table with records.

**Roles**

```
Administrator
Manager
Employee
```

**Users**

```
User 1
User 2
User 3
```

Now i want to create a relationship between these two tables, in this situation each user can have only one role but how do i express this relation?

To be more specific is it the **user row** in the table that can have only one role or the users table as a whole?

If it is the users table as a whole that can have only one role then in a situation where **User 1** and **User 2** are both administrators will the relationship then become **many to many**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might start by reviewing the documentation on relationships in Laravel/Eloquent: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Your classes will look something like this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role');
    }
}

class Role extends Model
{
}
```

This means that each `User` has one `Role` - it doesn't prevent the same role from belonging to multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

I seems it will become.

Role model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

User model

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}
```

so means, a Role can have many users and a user belongs to a role.

so User1 and User2 can be both Administrators. Check out  [laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/14) for additional info on relationship

Answer (score 1):

I think, will be better, to use ManyToMany in Role-User reations, because, if you want now to use one role for one user, in future, probably, you will need to user more than one role to user. Also, ManyToMany not slower, than One-to-Many, but it more powerfull decision.

Role model

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

User model

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
}
```